# Can We Affect Visibility of Review History?

Tags: content-editor, editor-user-permissions

In the Content Editor of `Sitecore 9`, there's a dropdown on the `Review ribbon` for viewing the `History of an item` (who made what changes to it when, and so on).  It's not currently visible to very many users in our system.  This looks like a permissions issue; we'd like to change it but it's not clear where we might find this History item to address this.  I'm guessing somewhere in the Core database, but that's as near as I can get. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

The `Sitecore workflow panel` works a little bit differently and the workflow panel renders small buttons and added in a flag to decide whether it should be `disabled/greyed out`. This flag is only ever true if you are an administrator or if the item is locked also there are multiple conditions applied to enable/disable the buttons.

[image]

In the core database, `WorkflowPanel` item manages the workflow section under the review ribbon. You can find item at this path:`/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Workflow/WorkflowPanel`

[image]

The `WorkflowPanel` class is responsible to render small buttons. if you decompile the `Sitecore.Client.dll` you will get WorkflowPanel class and there is a method `Render()` that have certain conditions and one of the condition is checking if the `context item` has any workflow. If a workflow is not null for the item you will see the history button else it will not going to render the history button in the ribbon.

A condition that renders the history button.

```
if (workflow != null)
{
  RenderSmallButton(output, ribbon, Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control.GetUniqueID("B"), Translate.Text("History"), "Office/16x16/history.png", Translate.Text("Show the workflow history."), "item:workflowhistory", base.Enabled, down: false);
}
```

```
GetCommands(context.Items, out var workflow, out var commands);
        ....

if (workflow != null)
{
  RenderSmallButton(output, ribbon, Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control.GetUniqueID("B"), Translate.Text("History"), "Office/16x16/history.png", Translate.Text("Show the workflow history."), "item:workflowhistory", base.Enabled, down: false);
}


private static void GetCommands(Item[] items, out IWorkflow workflow, out WorkflowCommand[] commands)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(items, "items");
        Item item = items[0];
        if (item != null)
        {
            IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
            if (workflowProvider != null && workflowProvider.GetWorkflows().Length != 0)
            {
                workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);
                if (workflow != null && workflow.GetState(item) != null)
                {
                    commands = WorkflowFilterer.FilterVisibleCommands(workflow.GetCommands(item), item);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        workflow = null;
        commands = null;
    }
```

It is expected behavior and not a permission issue. You can validate the item that shows the history button for `user A` and check the same item for `user B`. Ensure users are members of at least `sitecore\Sitecore Client Users`
`sitecore\Author`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like something that is provided out of the box, I'm not aware of any such drop down.

There is a chance someone has installed Audit trail plugin previously (or something like this).

Either way you should be able to configure access to items in the review ribbon by adjusting permissions in the security editor. Once there navigate to core database and then this location `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Strips/Review/AuditTrail`

If not audit trail plugin then you should find something in similar location

Comment: I should probably have mentioned this History button/dropdown is in the Workflow section of the Review ribbon.  There's no indication of anything below the Workflow item in the Core content tree, though.